# Run a .js script when bundling react native code with Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have this script:

```
 node src/runlink.js
```

that I'm running with npm run link but I would like to run it when building my code with Xcode.

is there any way to do that ? I tried to do it with the build phase but haven't succeed

Comment: So the script needs to run before you npm start? or at the same time? maybe try to look into your package.json and add the run script to npm start script if it works for you.

Comment: The script need to run at the start, it's already in the package.json but I need to make it work when I'm building for IOS automatically

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a script in Build Phases.

1. On the `Project Navigator` (left column) select your project.
2. Then on the Targets select your desired target
3. Clic on `Build Phases` tab
4. Click on the + sign to create `New Run Script Phase`
   [image]
5. Type `node "${SRCROOT}/../src/runlink.js"`
   [image]

Comment: thank you, I actually did it before and the build succeed but for some reason the script is not running... any ideas why ?

Comment: @Elon make sure script file has permissions to be executable (chmod +x)